# How to get task completed count for pool

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, runnable

```
class {

private ExecutorService pool;

public void go() {

pool = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
pool.shutdown(); 
//logger.log(Level.INFO, "Actual db records added = ["+  + "]");

} //end go 

public void update() {

pool.submit(new ItemDispatcher(lse));

} //end update 


} //end class




public class ItemDispatcher implements Runnable {
//do work
}
```

I'm looking to log the total number of execution tasks that completed for my above scenario. How can I do this. each time on update() method, I submit a task to `ItemDispatcher`. I want to know how many times tasks completed after I call shutdown on pool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the pool itself keeps those sort of figures. You can do it yourself fairly easily though:

Have an `AtomicInteger`, have each task increment the `AtomicInteger` when it starts running.